# Create filter aggregation in spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I recently started exploring Aggregation Framework in MongoDB with SpringData.
I could Create following query i.e

```
db.consumer_order.aggregate([
                            { $match: {_id: ObjectId("59e43f542397a00de0c688e4"), "orderState":"Confirmed"}},
                            { $project: {
                                parts: {$filter: {
                                    input: '$parts',
                                    as: 'item',
                                    cond: {$eq: ['$$item.currentState', "Estimation Confirmed"]}
                                }}
                            }}
                        ])
```

with MongoDB Native Driver in Spring with the following Code

```
List<Document> aggrigationList = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
conditions.add("$$item.currentState");
conditions.add("Estimation Confirmed");

Document matchDoc = new Document("$match",new Document("_id",new ObjectId(orderId)));
Document projectDoc = new Document("$project",new Document("parts",new Document("$filter",new Document("input","$parts").append("as", "item").append("cond", new Document("$eq",conditions)))));
aggrigationList.add(matchDoc);
aggrigationList.add(projectDoc);

Document orderWithPendingParts = consumerOrderCollection.aggregate(aggrigationList).first();
```

But I do know it's not a good practice to work always with Native Driver since we've Spring-Data in hand. But I'm having trouble to construct the above MongoDB query to AggrigationObject Using Spring Data. I tried with the below, But find difficulty in Constructing **Aggregation.project()** i.e

```
mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("owner").is(user).andOperator(Criteria.where("orderState").is("confirmed"))),
            ***Finding Difficulty in here***
            ), inputType, outputType)
```

Guide me, If I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try below query.

Static Imports

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.Filter.filter;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf;
```

Code

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
           project().and(filter("parts")
             .as("item")
             .by(valueOf(
                  "item.currentState")
                   .equalToValue(
                  "Estimation Confirmed")))
          .as("parts");
);

List<outputType> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, inputType, outputType)
```

Comment: Getting error since project method takes array of strings as parameters like project(String... fields), but you've specified Array Operators as parameters. Or Did I miss something

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it. It's working without errors. But when it comes to fetching results it's slightly different, when I'm expecting one document as a result, it's fetching multiple. Are you sure It matches exactly with above query I've mentioned? Because the query I've mentioned is what to be aggregated in spring. Thank you one more time for your patience :)

Comment: Np. This is the generated query `[ { "$project" : { "parts" : { "$filter" : { "input" : "$parts" , "as" : "item" , "cond" : { "$eq" : [ "$$item.currentState" , "Estimation Confirmed"]}}}}}]`. Are you sure your match is working correctly ?

Comment: Can you add a document each which is expected and one which is not expected along  with your updated query to the post ?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the late. I was on leave.

Comment: Oops!! my bad. My Match query is wrong. Your answer worked absolutely perfect :) Thank you.

Comment: Any idea how can i use **regex** inside ``equalToValue("Estimation Confirmed")``. Like if i give **est**. it should return the related data. @SagarVeeram

Comment: Any idea how I can use an in clause instead of equalTo?