# Spring data mongodb aggregation filter by list

Tags: arrays, spring, mongodb, filter, aggregation

I followed the example in this question [Create filter aggregation in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767750/create-filter-aggregation-in-spring/46769125#46769125) to create filter in aggregation on spring data mongodb. In the example the filter search by **valueOf** and **equalToValue** to create an $eq. How can I create an $in and pass a list?


This is my code:

```
ProjectionOperation p2 = project()
            .andExpression("name").as("name")
            .andExpression("version._id").as("version._id")
            .andExpression("version.version").as("version.version")
            .and(filter("version.cat")
                    .as("cat")
                    .by(valueOf("cat._id")
                            .equalToValue(new ObjectId("5de99f42f15273c92d1228e8"))))
            .as("version.cat");
```

and I'm looking for something like this:

```
**ProjectionOperation p2 = project()
            .andExpression("name").as("name")
            .andExpression("version._id").as("version._id")
            .andExpression("version.version").as("version.version")
            .and(filter("version.cat")
                    .as("cat")
                    .by(new Criteria("cat")
                            .in(Arrays.asList(
                                    new ObjectId("5de99f42f15273c92d1228f7"),
                                    new ObjectId("5de99f42f15273c92d1228f9"))
                            )
                            .getCriteriaObject()
                    )).as("version.cat"));
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You can do it by performing unwind, match and group operation on data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can resolve this problem with **ArrayOperators**:

```
ProjectionOperation p2 = project()
            .andExpression("name").as("name")
            .andExpression("version._id").as("version._id")
            .andExpression("version.version").as("version.version")
            .and(filter("version.cat")
                    .as("cat")
                    .by(
                            ArrayOperators.In
                                    .arrayOf(Arrays.asList(
                                            new ObjectId("5de99f42f15273c92d1251853"),
                                            new ObjectId("5de99f42f15273c92d1251854"),
                                    )
                                    ).containsValue("$$cat._id")))
            .as("version.cat");
```

In arrayOf I pass the list that I want to compare with the value of each objectId. I think, the filter makes some class of 'for' to get each value of the cat list.

Comment: Hi Carlos Ruiz, Do you have any idea on how to add another condition with ArrayOperators.Filter ? posted below stackoverflow question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534705/spring-mongo-aggregation-filter-with-and-in-and-eq-conditions

Comment: Hi @PrabaharanKathiresan. Sorry I don't have idea to get that. I think you have to create more pipelines to simulate many conditions. Do one filter and the result, make it another.

Comment: arrayOf does not take.a list parameter. Please look at the definition of the function. As such, this code is not going to work.