# How to use MongoTemplate cond and filter in java code?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How  to use in springframework_data_mongodb  like image?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h3gy.png)

Comment: Please include the text (the query) from the image within the post. Also, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See this post with similar question: [Create filter aggregation in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767750/create-filter-aggregation-in-spring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code specific to your problem if you use **Java 8** and **Spring Data MongoDB 3.0.3.RELEASE**.

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.match;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.project;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.Filter.filter;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;

MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "database");
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation =  project().and(filter("fields")
                 .as("field")
                 .by(Eq.valueOf("field.code").equalToValue("EngName")))
                 .as("fields");
MatchOperation matchOperation = match(where("fields.value").in("A","B"));
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(projectionOperation,matchOperation);
AggregationResults<Document> docs = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "collection", Document.class);
        
docs.forEach(doc->System.out.println(doc));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from MongoDB manual for [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#example) aggregation converted to Spring Data MongoDB code. The same syntax can be applied to the question about using the `$filter` along with a *condition*.

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                      project()
                         .and(filter("items")
                              .as("item")
                              .by(Gte.valueOf("item.price").greaterThanEqualToValue(100)))
                         .as("items")
);
        
AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "sales", Document.class);        
results.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

**Reference:** [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.Filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ArrayOperators.Filter.html).

Comment: @Wei Please take a look at the example I had posted, and tell if it is useful. You can ask for any clarifications.