# Spring Aggregations - Filter by many conditions

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation

I followed this to use aggregations in spring. [Create filter aggregation in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767750/create-filter-aggregation-in-spring/46769125#46769125)

I can filter by one condition. But how to filter by many conditions. I want to filter by 3 conditions as below.(cond section) please help

```
 db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "metadata.type": "UNPAID",
      "metadata.syncStatus": "OK",
      "metadata.paymentStatus": "UNKNOWN",
      "planName": "myplan",
      "environment": "PREPROD",
      "country": "sl"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      planName: 1,
      phoneNumber: 1,
      time: 1,
      metadata: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$metadata",
          as: "metadata",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$metadata.type",
                  "UNPAID"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$metadata.syncStatus",
                  "OK"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$metadata.paymentStatus",
                  "UNKNOWN"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```